# Bluetooth connection lost after send message (BluetoothChat)

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to connect my Droid to OBDKey I use BluetoothChat as example to connect via bluetooth  I connect to OBDKey succesfully but after send message to OBDKey connection lost

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

How are you assessing a "successful" and "lost" connection?

When you connect, send "ATZ\r" and you will see the OBDKey blue LED flash 3 times.